# How to convert int RGB into BYTE 2D array gray image

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to convert a colored image to a gray scaled one and save it as BYTE values into a 2D array and later I need to do some process on this 2D array. Although, my array's values are all bytes, my output image turns blue instead of gray. Can anyone help me please ? 
Here is my code :

```
public class HW {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] savedImage = readimage(new File("C:\\Images\\input.jpg"));

    BufferedImage grayImage = new BufferedImage(savedImage.length, savedImage[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    for (int i =0 ; i<savedImage.length ; i ++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<savedImage[0].length ; j++){
            grayImage.setRGB(i, j, savedImage[i][j]);
            System.out.print(savedImage[i][j] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    try {
        File outputfile = new File ("C:\\Images\\garyoutput.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(grayImage, "jpg", outputfile);
    }
    catch(IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static int[][] readimage(File filename) throws IOException {
    // Grayscale Image output
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(filename);

    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int [][] readimageVal = new int [width][height];

    for (int i = 0; i<height ; i++) {
        for (int j =0  ; j<width ; j++) {
            int p = img.getRGB(j,i);

            int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
            int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
            int b = p&0xff;

            int avg = ((r+b+g)/3);

            readimageVal[j][i] = avg;
        }
    }
    return readimageVal;
}
```

}

Comment: You set the wrong image pixel/byte type. Try using `new BufferedImage(savedImage.length, savedImage[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the main nested loops in the `main` method:

```
for (int i =0 ; i<savedImage.length ; i ++){
    for (int j=0 ; j<savedImage[0].length ; j++){
           grayImage.setRGB(i, j, savedImage[i][j]);//← Here
        System.out.print(savedImage[i][j] + ",");
    }
}
```

`int[][] savedImage` contains one byte representing the gray value, but `grayImage` is still type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`. So, if you only call `grayImage.setRGB(i, j, savedImage[i][j])`, only the blue portion of the `int` will be set:

```
RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
00000000 00000000 xxxxxxxx
```

So you need to call this instead:

```
int rgb = savedImage[i][j];
rgb = (rgb<<16)|(rgb<<8)|(rgb);
grayImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have different possibilities to do it, but first, here is a simpler way to access the pixels:

```
public static int[][] readimage(File filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(filename) ;// Grayscale Image output
    final int width = img.getWidth() ;
    final int height = img.getHeight() ;
    int[][] graylevelarray = new int[height][width] ;

    for (int y=0 ; y < height ; y++)
        for (int x=0 ; x < width ; x++) {
            int r = img.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 0) ;
            int g = img.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 1) ;
            int b = img.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 2) ;
            graylevelarray[y][x] = ??? ;
            }

    return graylevelarray ;
    }
```

As I said, for the conversion, you have many different possibilities:

- An average as you did, but it's rarely used.
- CIE 601 (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B) or CIE 709 (0.2125*R + 0.7154*G + 0.0721*B) recommandations, the most used.
- Cheap/fast green (R+2*G+B)/4, that is faster, used for example into the library Zxing.